# Prove simplification of summation

Tags: summation

I have the following equation:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n 2-\frac{2i}{n} $$

When running it with different values of $n$, the result seems to always be $ n - 1 $ so that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n 2-\frac{2i}{n} = n - 1 $$

How can I expand the equation to prove that this is always true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^n(2 - \frac{2i}{n}) = 2\sum_{i=0}^n1 - \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=0}^ni = 2n - \frac{2}{n}\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 2n - (n+1) = n - 1$$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: $\sum_{i=1}^n a=na,\ \sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: Cheers, I can see how these rules are being used in the other more detailed answer :)